# ADD Places search box

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm developing my own map with google API.
This is my start example http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/speed_test_example.html

How can i add Places search box in this map? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

i'm a beginner :)
Thanks
Eleonora

Answer (score 0):

Please see the JavaScript+HTML Example on exactly that Google-Developer Page.

You have to specify an input box, like

```
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

and do the JavaScript stuff like

```
[...]

var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));

[...]
```

But all of that is listed on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox.

Comment: thank you... i've add <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box"> in my html. But the problem is with js, in which file i must add the code? and all the code or some line?

Comment: You have to do other stuff, not just only add the input box. There is some JavaScript you should also implement, so the box works.

Comment: for me is little difficult integrate the existing code speed_test_example.html with the code for the search box

Comment: I recommend that you first learn HTML + JavaScript before you implement/combine such projects/examples.

Comment: thanks for your time, but I think that alone will not succeed. Thanks anyway.